# Difference between .php extension and AddType

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

Since I want to have PHP code run properly on my website, should I add

`AddType application/x-httpd-php .html`

to my htaccess file, or just change all of my `*.html` files into `*.php` files?

I've heard that changing the file extension to `*.php` causes the website to load slower, but I'm wondering if changing the htaccess file does the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either way, the files will be passed through the PHP interpreter, making them ever-so-slightly slower than if they were plain HTML files directly served down. It's the same process however you set it up.  The difference in speed from plain HTML is going to be quite small unless you have a lot of dynamic PHP in there. Given that you are considering renaming existing files from `.html` to `.php`, I suspect you *don't* have much PHP code in there already (or any).

So it doesn't really matter which way you handle it.

#### However...

Leaving them as `.html` has the possible disadvantage that if you ever *forget* to setup this configuration, you could wind up serving raw PHP code to the browser, which might include your database connection details or other secrets.

Answer (score 0):

it does exactly the same. .php is not slower than html, html is not slower than php, just a different setting in your webserver config.

AddType application/x-httpd-php .html would be a fraction slower, as apache load this line dynamically. If you set it in httpd.conf it would be exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Michael that you need to be careful with renaming them HTML and having the chance that it not be setup, or your host provider do something screwy with your account.

If you do this, make sure any database/password files remain as PHP that you simply include in your HTML file.